# Help with jQuery .next

Tags: jquery, css

I think I could use .next on this, not sure, if there's a better way please let me know. I have a tab set up with an UL, each LI in the UL has a 1px dotted border on the bottom except the "active" li. The "active" tab has a background image. I need to remove the border if the LI after any LI has the class active.

```
<ul id="flowtabs">
  <li><a href="t1">Analysis</a></li>
  <li><a href="t2">Manual Trading</a></li>
  <li><a href="t3" class="active">Automatic Trading</a></li>
  <li><a href="t4">Simulate</a></li>
  <li><a href="t5">Connect</a></li>
  <li><a href="t6">Extend</a></li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#flowtabs li a').hasClass('active').next('css','border','none')
}
```

I would want `<a href="t2">` and `<a href="t4">` to have their border removed, and have this applied any time a li has the class active.

I don't think the construction is right, is there a better way to remove the border from the LI before and after the one that has the class 'active'

here's an image to help: http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/5384/screenshot20100907at147.png

Thanks!

Comment: Based on the example image you provided, I think what you actually want is to remove the border from the node with "active, and the one immediately before it.  Since the border is on the bottom of each li, that would remove the two borders surrounding the active node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you specifically asked for, removing the border from the `<li>`s on either side of the active `<li>`:

```
$(function() {
    $('#flowtabs li a.active').parent('li').next().add($('#flowtabs li a.active').parent('li').prev()).css('border','none');
});
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WUu2F/

This does what I think you actually want, which I mentioned in my comment on your question:

```
$(function() {
    $('#flowtabs li a.active').parent('li').prev().andSelf().children('a').css('border','none');
});
```

And a demo of that: http://jsfiddle.net/k5sur/

Comment: Here's the working code: http://www.kinetick.com/V3/tour
I would want the border removed on Manual trading, the one above it. I am targeting the anchor in the li, as the a.active is wider than the normal a

Comment: Yes, you will want the second of my suggestions.

Comment: @Ender - thank you! works perfect, now I need to add a border to the top of the UL (same as li's) and remove it if the first child li is 'active'  something like $('#flowtabs.firstChild')? Nevermind that won't work, Ill have to create another class ".first" that has border top and bottom, so this works perfect. thanks a lot man, I did not know you could chain 4 selectors together like that (parent, prev, self, children)

Comment: @Dirty Bird - IMO one of the best parts of jQuery is the ability to chain together as many selectors as you like :)

Comment: If I had a bg image at the top of the UL, how would I remove it if the first child of the UL is 'active'....

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(
    function ()
    {
        $('#flowtabs li a.active').filter(function(i) { return i > 0; }).parent('li').css('border', 'none');
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PxmqG/

This will remove the border around the `li a.active`s that appear AFTER the first `li a.active`.

---

Your question is a little confusing, so I think after a second read-through I understand better what you want.

```
$(document).ready(
    function ()
    {
        $('#flowtabs li a.active').parent('li').prev('li').css('border-bottom','none').end().next('li').css('border-top', 'none');
    }
);
```

This will remove the borders on the `li`s BEFORE and AFTER EVERY `li a.active`. I added this because of your explanation and image.

---

**Revision 3**

```
$(document).ready(
    function ()
    {
        $('#flowtabs li a.active').css('border-bottom', 'none').parent('li').prev('li').children('a').css('border-bottom','none');
    }
);
```

This removes the `border` from your `current` and `previous` `li` tags. Seems to be what you've been wanting from the beginning, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it the opposite way and add the underline to the `li` with the `active` class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#flowtabs li a').hasClass('active').parent('li').css('border','none');
}
```

However, if you want to do it that way. Then there are some questions. What about `li` before the `active` `li`? Either way `next` would be targeting the `a` elements and not the `li`. This would remove the border from all `li`'s except the one with the `active` `a`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#flowtabs li a').hasClass('active').parent('li').siblings().css('border','none')
}
```

Comment: See my update, either should work. You cannot use `next` based on the documentation "Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements."

Answer (score 0):

may be you can do something like thisL

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#flowtabs li a').not('.active').css('border','none');
});
```

This means any 'a' tag except the one with class 'active' -> remove border.